# Optimizing and improving a `username` regex

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have created this `Regex` to validate usernames which I need in my projects:

```
^(?=.{3,32}$)(?!.*[._-]{2})(?!.*[0-9]{5,})[a-z](?:[\w]*|[a-z0-9\.]*|[a-z0-9-]*)[a-z0-9]$
```

It works just fine; but I'm wondering if there is any improvement and optimization for it, since I'm not exactly a regex-guy.

The regex and tests are available [here](http://rubular.com/r/yOsv5oM1rI).

Rules are:

- usernames should start with `[a-z]`
- usernames should end with `[a-z0-9]`
- usernames can have a length between 3 and 32
- usernames can contain any of `[a-z0-9\._-]`
- Numbers should not be in the vicinity of each other more than 4 times. I mean `p1234` is a match and `p12345` is not.
- each username can contains only one of `[\._-]`. I mean a username can contain `.` or `-` or `_`
- each `.`, `-`, and `_` should be followed by an alpha-numeric. I mean a `.` can not be followed by another `.`. They should not be in the vicinity of each other.

Tests:

```
j1vad-amiry            match
j1vad-ami-ry           match
ja23d_am8ry            match
ja_23d_am8ry           match
jav5d2.am3y            match
jav.ad.amiry           match
jav.ad.ami.ry.2        match
ja3fd4                 match
page2491               match
page24915              not match
jav-ad_amiry           not match
javad_am-iry           not match
jav.ami-ry             not match
jav.ami_ry             not match
jav.ami__ry            not match
2jav                   not match
2jav_ad                not match
2jav_ad3               not match
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would split it into several checks. That way you could report what exactly is wrong with a particular username, not just "it is wrong". PS: `performance` tag doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: Looks like a topic for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not SO.

Comment: @HABO I didn't know about `CodeReview` site; Thanks to mention. I'm checking it now.

Comment: @zerkms I removed `performance` tag

Comment: You don't *have* to use regex for all of it, right? It's much easier to check length in C# for example.